# Past depression affect my ability to obtain a Canadian medical certificate?

Tags: medical, transport-canada

I'm from Canada, and two years ago I had problems with my wife and decided to divorce. After that, I felt discomfort, and I was diagnosed with depression.

I took an antidepressant Effexor for one year. But another doctor decided to stop my medication because he believed that it was normal to be sad after divorce, and I lm not a depressed person! so I have taken no medication in the last year. I think that the first doctor had made a mistake by giving me this medication.

Should I still be able to qualify for a medical 1 in Canada?

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27345/will-having-a-history-of-depression-prevent-me-from-flying

Comment: This question is different from [Will having a history of depression prevent me from flying?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/27345/will-having-a-history-of-depression-prevent-me-from-flying), which is asking about the USA. This question is about Canada.

Comment: Edited the post and retracted my close vote.

Comment: @DanieleProcida While you are right that this question is specifically about Canada and the linked duplicated is about the US, I don't think the answer will be any different. The linked question is answered with **ask an AME because every case is different and this cannot be answered by strangers online**, so that is what you should do in Canada as well.