# History of Epilepsy- want to apply for medical

Tags: medical

I have a history of epilepsy when I was in high school/first 2 years of college due to a few brain surgeries I had as an infant. I still take medication for them. I know this sounds like an automatic DQ. But I have not had a seizure in a few years and have had multiple brain scans that show normal brain activity since my last episode. Could this possibly be used as evidence for being medically fit to fly?

Comment: You have to ask a medical examiner that question. Nobody here can answer it. Even if someone here says maybe possibly, you still have to go see an aviation examiner.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's only answerable by an aviation medical examiner with full access to medical records and tests.

Comment: @GdD I  vote to leave it open for awhile.  John K's comment is an answer. Let's help the OP out a bit.

Comment: Different question, but this answer (talk to an AME) applies: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/27346/7532

Comment: Schedule a CONSULT with an Aviation Medical Examiner and see what he/she says. Do NOT go in for a regular FAA airmen's physical. If you've ever been denied a medical certificate, you cannot fly a light sport aircraft (that doesn't require an FAA medical certificate). If your consult looks like you could never get (or not likely get) an FAA medical certificate, you could still fly LSA if you chose.

Comment: @RetiredATC [14 CFR 61.23 (c)(2)(iv)](https://www.ecfr.gov/current/title-14/chapter-I/subchapter-D/part-61/subpart-A/section-61.23) *"Not know or have reason to know of any medical condition that would make that person unable to operate a light-sport aircraft in a safe manner."* Pretty sure known history of epilepsy would fall under that.

Comment: @Ron Beyer There are certainly medical conditions that would indicate a person shouldn't operate an LSA aircraft. Does the OP have one? I don't know. I don't know how long it has been since his last event. I don't know what medicine he is on. I also don't know if he has been issued a driver's license from his state. Those are factors (and probably others) one would have to take into consideration prior to beginning LSA flight. My advice was to make sure the OP knew that if he/she were denied a medical certificate LSA flight would not be a possibility.

Comment: I've voted to keep this question open. It is not strictly per norms here, but has huge educational value IMO.

Comment: NO. Epilectics are not allowed to be licensed pilots under very explicit FAA rules. There is more or less zero chance you can get a medical of any type if you disclose your condition.

Answer (score 4):

Obviously the answer here depends on consultation with your AME.  However, there are some ***incredibly useful*** resources from the FAA for each and every disqualifying condition.  I highly recommend you review these resources, and then discuss them with your primary care physician first, and then consult with an AME.  All of these links are to FAA sources:

1. Here is [the questionnaire](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/Airman_Seizure_Questionnaire.pdf) that you will actually review with the AME, so you can print it *right now* and review it first with yourself, and then with your physician or psychiatrist before proceeding to an AME.
2. [FAA Psychiatric and Psychological Evaluation Specification](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/ppevalspecs.pdf) or the similar [FAA Psychological Evaluation Specification](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/psychiatricevalspecs.pdf)
3. Consider contacting an AME who is part of the [HIMS program](https://www.faa.gov/sites/faa.gov/files/pilots/medical/HIMS%20INDEPENDENT%20MEDICAL%20SPONSORS.pdf), they are designated to help people with mental health issues assess their eligibility.

For all conditions, the FAA publishes guides that inform both the pilot and the AME about the specific criteria that can lead to issuance, AME Assisted Special Issuance (AASI), disqualification, etc.

***Always*** research your particular condition starting with [this FAA page](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/dec_cons/disease_prot/) before deciding whether or not to proceed further.

Comment: Please add a warning not to apply in MedXpress until the AME has confirmed OP will pass.  Until then, they should only schedule consultations (not exams) to avoid disqualifying themself from Sport.

Answer (score 2):

Well, since you specifically ask *"Could this possibly be used as evidence for being medically fit to fly?"* I will offer the obvious answer *yes, it can be offered as evidence*.

This site, even with all the wisdom and knowledge gathered together, cannot answer the question whether or not that evidence will be considered valid by AME.

Most importantly you should ask yourself whether you honestly consider yourself fit to fly? Having a medical condition such as epilepsy has, unfortunately,  great potential to put you and other people in great danger. An epileptic seizure while flying solo will almost certainly lead to at least one fatality.

I've offered myself as an example in these kind of questions popping up here. I fully understand the keen interest in aviation as a hobby (and often as a profession too). It is pretty much the most exiting thing one can do with clothes on. As such it sometimes may blur ones judgement. My judgement was blurred in the sense that I have a medical condition that as such will automatically prevent me from obtaining a medical, but I was "fine" for years and years. I was able to get medical statements that convinced AME to grant me a medical and up in the air I was. Untill, luckily while on ground, I had two consecutive medical events in short succesion. I considered myself lucky, and quite happily grounded myself and have not flown since. It may be exiting, but not worth dying for.

Airplanes, especially smaller ones are physiologically (and psychologically) more or less hostile environments. There is a lot of physical stimuli and sensory load present all the time, and should one be susceptible to adverse medical events, the risk of that happening is greatly elevated while flying.

Answer (score 2):

The information listed here is great but I think there is one important missing piece, you note:

> I still take medication for them.

[If you look at the FAA's Do Not Issue/Do Not Fly list here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/pharm/dni_dnf/) it specifically calls out:

> **Seizure medications**, even if used for non-seizure conditions such as migraines

and later on (bolded for emphasis)

> **Do Not Fly**. Airmen **should not fly while using any of the medications
> in the Do Not Issue section above or while using any of the
> medications or classes/groups of medications listed below without an
> acceptable wait time after the last dose.** All of these medications may
> cause sedation (drowsiness) and impair cognitive function, seriously
> degrading pilot performance. This impairment can occur even when the
> individual feels alert and is apparently functioning normally - in
> other words, the airman can be "unaware of impair."

In the eyes of the FAA its not only about controlling the issue but in some cases having it controlled and being medication free.

As always, you should seek the advice of an AME as they are the only *actual* authority on this matter.